# How can I start a bounty in a mobile application?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bounties

I was browsing some questions in Chemistry Stack Exchange. Many of the questions were relevant to me but either they had no answers or outdated ones. So I wanted to start a bounty on them. But this feature is not shown in the app. How can I use it in a mobile app?

Comment: It's not currently in the mobile app

Comment: @Catija what do you mean? As clearly said, this is simply not possible via the app, only in the site itself. (Probably API doesn't support bounties yet)

Comment: @Catija oh. lol. Well, "play" and "place" do sound similar... :/